# Combine output of two queries without using union or temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table IDValues

| ID | Unique ID | Sort Order | Start Date | End Date | Changed | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 501 | 23 | 2 | 2011-01-14 | 2011-12-19 | 0 | 664 |
| 302 | 15 | 9 | 2021-03-05 | 2021-04-27 | 0 | 223 |
| 351 | 31 | 6 | 2017-08-18 | 2017-10-16 | 0 | 765 |
| 501 | 27 | 3 | 2011-12-20 | 2012-01-15 | 1 | 416 |
| 501 | 19 | 1 | 2010-12-29 | 2011-01-03 | 0 | 519 |
| 351 | 26 | 3 | 2016-01-19 | 2016-03-11 | 0 | 364 |
| 501 | 21 | 4 | 2012-01-16 | 2012-05-15 | 1 | 447 |
| 302 | 14 | 10 | 2021-04-28 | 2021-05-15 | 1 | 776 |
| 413 | 41 | 5 | 2018-08-20 | 2018-12-11 | 0 | 679 |
| 455 | 41 | 7 | 2017-11-23 | 2018-01-25 | 1 | 456 |

I need to find the IDs and their details with Changed=1 and Sort Order=x along with IDs having Sort Order=x-1, i.e., the IDs with previous Sort Order (if exists).

Also for IDs with Sort Order=x, I have to find the number of days = Number of days from StartDate to end of the  month
And for IDs with Sort Order=x-1, I have to find the number of days= Number of days from start of the month till EndDate.

I tried doing it in two parts and using a temporary table and combining both the results.

```
Select *, DATEDIFF(d,StartDate,eomonth(StartDate)) as NoOfDays
into #temptbl
from IDDetails where Changed=1

Select A.*, day(EndDate) as NoOfDays from IDDetails A inner join #temptbl B
on A.ID=B.ID and A.SortOrder= B.SortOrder-1
```

When I combine these results, I get the desired output. But I don't want to use a temporary table or union function. Below is the output I need. Is there any other way I can get the output without writing two queries?

Output:

| ID | Unique ID | Sort Order | Start Date | End Date | Changed | Value | No. of days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 501 | 23 | 2 | 2011-01-14 | 2011-12-19 | 0 | 664 | 19 |
| 302 | 15 | 9 | 2021-03-05 | 2021-04-27 | 0 | 223 | 27 |
| 501 | 27 | 3 | 2011-12-20 | 2012-01-15 | 1 | 416 | 12 |
| 501 | 21 | 4 | 2012-01-16 | 2012-05-15 | 1 | 447 | 16 |
| 302 | 14 | 10 | 2021-04-28 | 2021-05-15 | 1 | 776 | 3 |
| 501 | 27 | 3 | 2011-12-20 | 2012-01-15 | 1 | 416 | 15 |
| 455 | 41 | 7 | 2017-11-23 | 2018-01-25 | 1 | 456 | 25 |

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL-Server`?

Comment: @apanda . . . Based on the syntax of the query, I assume you are using SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: You could use a CTE instead of a temporary table. Also, why not use a temporary table?

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic I am using SQL-Server. My mistake I had added the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct option is simply to use nested queries.  Take your first query and nest it within your second query...

```
Select
  A.*, day(EndDate) as NoOfDays
from
  IDDetails A
inner join
(
  Select
    *,
    DATEDIFF(d,StartDate,eomonth(StartDate)) as NoOfDays
  from
    IDDetails
  where
    Changed = 1
)
  B
    on  A.ID        = B.ID
    and A.SortOrder = B.SortOrder - 1
```

That itself can be simplified further to just being a simple self-join...

```
SELECT
  A.*, day(EndDate) as NoOfDays
FROM
  IDDetails A
INNER JOIN
  IDDetails B
    on  A.ID        = B.ID
    and A.SortOrder = B.SortOrder - 1
WHERE
  B.Changed = 1
```

Notes:

- `day(EndDate)` is ambiguous in all cases; both `A` and `B` have an `EndDate`, specify `A.EndDate` or `B.EndDate`
- You create  `NoOfDays` column in `B`, then don't use it in the second query

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use temporary tables, maybe you want ot use Common Expression Table (CTE) it's a nice and readable way for that kind of prupose

So this code :

```
Select *, DATEDIFF(d,StartDate,eomonth(StartDate)) as NoOfDays
into #temptbl
from IDDetails where Changed=1

Select A.*, day(EndDate) as NoOfDays from IDDetails A inner join #temptbl B
on A.ID=B.ID and A.SortOrder= B.SortOrder-1
```

Becomes this :

```
With _Changed1 AS (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(d,StartDate,eomonth(StartDate)) AS NoOfDays
    FROM IDDetails 
    WHERE Changed=1
)
SELECT A.*, day(EndDate) AS NoOfDays 
FROM IDDetails A 
INNER JOIN _Changed1 B
ON A.ID=B.ID 
AND A.SortOrder= B.SortOrder-1
```

Answer (score -1):

Join both select results by code, for example merging them in one array.